# Android : Setting default zoom level for an area with com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I am working on an Android application in which I would like to show user the nearby area to his location. Unfortunately, when I get map data from GoogleMaps, it shows me the entire world and just a dot on the present location and I need to keep zooming in. I tried to set the zoom factor upto 100, but that didn't change anything. Is there something I am doing wrong. Kindly let me know.

Here is my code :

```
   public class MapsActivitiyFragment extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

   static GoogleMap googleMap;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;
    LatLng myPosition;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_maps_activitiy);

        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        googleMap = fm.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null) {
            circleDraw(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            zoomIn(location.getLatitude(), location.getLatitude());
            onLocationChanged(location);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    public void circleDraw(double i, double ii) {

        googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(i, ii))
                .radius(10000).strokeColor(Color.BLACK).strokeWidth(5)
                .fillColor(Color.argb(50, 238, 116, 116)));
    }

    public void zoomIn(double Lat, double Long) {

        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(Lat,
                Long));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
        googleMap.moveCamera(center);
        googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        googleMap.clear();// clean the map
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        circleDraw(latitude, longitude);
        zoomIn(latitude, longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

*Update*

Image : [image: Lcoation image after manual zoom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember that `onLocationChanged` is invoked when you're position is changed. If you stand still you can have a problem with getting it also you will have a lot of problems with that when you work on emulator.

Your code looks fine. Set zoom in the place were you setup you map. Don't set it in `onLocationChanged` In your code I would set the zoom in `onCreate`

// EDIT

```
LatLng center = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
CameraPosition.Builder cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder();
cameraPosition.target(center);
cameraPosition.zoom((int)configuration.get("zoom"));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition.build()));
```

Comment: Do i need to click on the button on top right corner to zoom or is it automatic??

Comment: if you set the map on start of your application then it will be automatic

Comment: I did as you said, and some new code to draw a circle. Both don't seem to work. I have edited my main post, can you please have a look.

Comment: do you even get to `zoomIn` method. Add some log to the `if` and this method and check. It look like you have no location so it does not know on which location it should zoom in. I think you `location` is null

Comment: No, location is shown, a blue dot, if I keep zooming in, it shows the correct location....Just the damn camera does not move or animate to zoom into the co-ordinates. And if location was null, I wouldnt see the blue dot. Should I send you a screenshot?

Comment: As you can see by the edited main post which contains a picture, I can zoom in manually  and it shows the correct location.

Comment: Look at my answer. I've added code from my application tested a lot of time. It is working properly. Compare it with your code

Comment: It finally worked when location was changed... When I moved around...Is there any way I can do it without moving??

Comment: if you have location then my code works for 100%. It is taken from my app 1:1. Everything you described looks like you have some problem with getting the location and getting to the part of code with setting zoom

Comment: I was able to zoom in too, only when location changed. Is there any way to bypass the mechanism where I only zoom in when location is changed. I tried to manually call the zoomin method on create, but it didn't help. That's the problem.

Comment: You can try to zoom with out invoking target(). Easy change in my code but I'm not sure will it work. Still you must understand that there is something wrong in your code because if you have location then my code will work for sure. btw you're code looks diffrent maybe this is the issue